# Enabling Project Functionality in a Docker Image of node_red

Tags: docker, node-red

I have branched both the node red git repo and the node red docker image and am trying to modify the settings.js file to enable Projects Functionality. The settings file that ends up in the Docker Container does not seem to be my modified one. My aim is to use the Docker image in a Cloud Foundry environment.

https://github.com/andrewcgaitskellhs2/node-red-docker.git

https://github.com/andrewcgaitskellhs2/node-red.git

I am also trying to install git and ssh-keygen at the time of the Docker build to allow Projects to function. I have added these in the Package.json files for both the node red app and image git repos.

If I need to start from scratch, please let me know what steps I need take.

I would welcome guidance on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You have explained what you are trying to do, but what is actually the problem? Also, please think about posting what you have tried, the code in settings.js if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be trying to install ssh-keygen and git via the `package.json` file.

You need to use the Node-RED Dockerfile as the base to build a new Docker container, in the Dockerfile you should use apt-get  to install them and to include an edited version of the `settings.js` Something like this:

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker
RUN  apt-get install git ssh-client
COPY settings.js /data
ENV FLOWS=flows.json
ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/src/node-red/node_modules:/data/node_modules

CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--userDir", "/data"]
```

Where `settings.js` is your edited version that is in the same directory as the Dockerfile

Edited following @knolleary's comment:

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker
COPY settings.js /data
ENV FLOWS=flows.json
ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/src/node-red/node_modules:/data/node_modules

CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--userDir", "/data"]
```

Comment: The nodered/node-red-docker image already contains everything you need for projects to work. You just need to add the settings file.

Comment: Thank you. This has worked and I can now deploy the docker image and Projects functionality is now available.  I am being asked by our system administrators to use the cloud foundry build packs and not Docker, but when I deploy the standard node-red app with a .cfignore file added to ignore node_modules and the project option added to the settings.js file, projects functionality does not initiate? Please can you suggest what I can try.  Thank you.

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to change the image. For persistence, you will mount a host directory into the container at `/data`, e.g. like this:

```
docker run --rm -d -v /my/node/red/data:/data -p 1880:1880 nodered/node-red
```

A `settings.js` file will get created in your data directory, here `/my/node/red/data`. Edit this file to enable projects, then restart the container.

It is also possible to place a `settings.js` file with projects enabled into the directory that you mount to `/data` inside the container before the first start.